CPM Modulation and Demodulation, How to determine the values for normalized bandwidth?
See table related to CPM Modulation which specifies $L$, $h$, $B_{norm}$ and sampling rate $f_s$. $B_{norm}$ and the sampling rate $f_s$ are directly related and I understand that relationship. What I want to know is how to compute other values for either $B_{norm}$ or $f_s$ other than what is listed already in the table based on using other possible values of $L$ and $h$ that are not listed. What is the formula that determined $f_s$ or  $B_{norm}$ based on $L$ and $h$??


Here are further details but the above is concisely my question:
Let me brief the problem I'm having.
Actually, I'm Working on modulation schemes to generate the dataset. However, there is a paper that computed these values of PSD, Fs, BER and so on based on the parameters that I have also set in my code as well. But I'm not getting the results similar, perhaps there's an issue with my code.
`
close all;
clear ;

% Parameters
M = 8; % Modulation order
h = 1/2; % Modulation index
L = 2; % Pulse length
BRF = 25e3; % RF bandwidth (25 kHz)
Ns = 8; % Upsampling factor
% Function to generate bit stream from image
originalImage = imread('image.jpg');
binaryArray = dec2bin(originalImage(:))';
binaryArray = binaryArray(:) - '0'; % Convert char to double (0 and 1)
bit_stream = binaryArray;
Fs = 2*BRF;
% Create CPM modulator and demodulator
cpmmodulator = comm.CPMModulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
    'FrequencyPulse', 'Rectangular', ...
    'ModulationIndex', h, ...
    'PulseLength', L, ...
    'BitInput', true, ...
    'SymbolMapping', 'Gray');
cpmdemodulator = comm.CPMDemodulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
    'FrequencyPulse', 'Rectangular', ...
    'ModulationIndex', h, ...
    'PulseLength', L, ...
    'BitOutput', true, ...
    'SymbolMapping', 'Gray');

% Generate CPM modulated signal
modulated_signal = cpmmodulator(bit_stream);

% Compute the Power Spectral Density (PSD)
[psd, f] = periodogram(modulated_signal, [], [], Fs, 'centered');

% Calculate total power
total_power = sum(psd);

% Calculate cumulative power
cumulative_power = cumsum(psd);

Bnorm = powerbw(modulated_signal);
Bnorm = Bnorm/pi;

`I have specified the

Bandwidth BRF = 25KHz
M(modulation order) = 8
h(modulation index) = 1/2
L(overlap factor) = 2

I know that the

fs = 2BRF/(Bnorm*NS)
Bnorm= normalized frequency
Ns = upsampling factor = 8

But to find Bnorm I have to plot 3dB PSD to get Bnorm.
What should be the initial fs?
The PSD Bnorm I'm getting is 0.603*pi pico rad/samples

Is your signal a passband signal or a baseband signal? Are you familiar with the Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem? If not reviewing that would be the next step and then provide more details here on what is still confusing you.

I'm quite familiar with the Shannon-Nyquist Sampling theorem. However the problem is that the CPM modulation scheme uses the above formula to compute its sampling frequency, which requires Bnorm in the first place, and Bnorm also requires Fs to compute it.
fs = 2BRF/(Bnorm*NS)
Bnorm= normalized frequency
Ns = upsampling factor = 8

I don't see how that has anything to do with computing the power spectral density. You can compute the power spectral density for any waveform using any Fs as long as the Fs is high enough to meet what is outlined by the Shannon-Nyquist theorem. When I'm not sure, I just use a higher Fs and then I review the PSD to see if the spectrum is sufficiently attenuated before I get to Nyquist. That approach would certainly apply to the spectrum for a modulated signal. Also to my first question-- is your signal a passband or baseband signal?

What it appears you are detailing is the minimum Fs, but you don't need the minimum Fs (and I wouldn't recommend it) to compute the PSD.  Maybe it's your title that is throwing me off here, and it's not actually a PSD that you want?

I have again briefed my problem in detail. It would be very helpful for me if you could brief this to me
Thanks

If you're asking to debug your Matlab code, that's typically out of the scope of this site. If you have a specific signal processing question beyond "why don't my results match", we can help you with that.

Sure, I do not need to debug my code. I just want to know how the fs and Bnorm in the table are varying. I mean to say both are dependent on each other i.e. are reciprocals to each other. How can I make it generic so that beyond this table values I can find good results?

I see-- you want to know what the full formula is based on the L and h values, is that correct?

Yes, exactly that is what I need

Can you add the reference to your post as to where that table came from?

Here’s a step-by-step procedure to find Bnorm:

Determine the highest frequency fmax​ in the signal.

Set the initial sampling frequency fs​≥2fmax​. You can start with fs=2.5fmax​ or fs=3fmax to ensure some margin.

Sample the signal at the chosen fs/

Compute the PSD: Use methods like the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to compute the Power Spectral Density of the sampled signal.

Plot the PSD: Plot the PSD on a log scale (dB) to visualize the 3dB points.

Identify 3dB Points: Locate the frequencies where the PSD drops by 3dB from its peak value.

Calculate Bnorm​: The bandwidth between these 3dB points represents the normalized bandwidth.


If you want to avoid the above method, just use analytical method assuming fs to be 4 times of the bandwidth, and derive the PSD to determine 3dB point.

OK; please explain how you can do Step 1 before you know the PSD of the signal? Your approach to solving Fatima's problem is basically "assuming you already have solved the problem, here's how you solve it".
